# How to get the component's key in Vue 3 composition setup() api?

Tags: vue.js

In the regular API I can get the key like this:

```
created()
{
    console.log(this._.vnode.key);
}
```

But in the composition API, in setup(), *'this'* is undefined. I tried to check the data and context properties, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from "vue";

setup() {
    const component = getCurrentInstance();
    console.log(component.vnode.key);
}
```